# Android IDE issue arises when I try to move layouts within tabHost

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So I'm currently working on an app, but to do so I am trying to work on multiple layouts within a tabHost. When I try to reorder the layouts within the tabHost it creates an IDE error, and then fails to render. I am experienced with java, but this is my first attempt at working with Android Studio.

Here's the error

```
Execute command
ActiveTool: com.intellij.designer.designSurface.tools.SelectionTool@3e7bfc0b
SDK: Android 6.0 - API 23
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadViewComponent.updateTag(RadViewComponent.java:105)
at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadViewComponent.updateTag(RadViewComponent.java:105)
at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadComponentOperations$1.run(RadComponentOperations.java:96)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:931)
at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadComponentOperations.moveComponent(RadComponentOperations.java:80)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AbstractEditOperation.execute(AbstractEditOperation.java:49)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.TreeDropToOperation.execute(TreeDropToOperation.java:34)
at com.intellij.designer.componentTree.TreeEditOperation.execute(TreeEditOperation.java:113)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.execute(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:1000)
at com.intellij.designer.designSurface.DesignerEditorPanel$DesignerToolProvider$3.run(DesignerEditorPanel.java:1004)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
at com.intellij.designer.designSurface.DesignerEditorPanel$DesignerToolProvider.execute(DesignerEditorPanel.java:1002)
at com.intellij.designer.componentTree.TreeDropListener.executeCommand(TreeDropListener.java:265)
at com.intellij.designer.componentTree.TreeDropListener.drop(TreeDropListener.java:91)
at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:455)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:538)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:852)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:776)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4736)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4611)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4457)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And the rendering software says

```
Exception raised during rendering: mBaselineAlignedChildIndex of
LinearLayout points to a View that doesn't know how to get its baseline.
```

Any help would be appreciated, and I don't think the XML file is important but here it is anyway

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.rtsd.morningtalk.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabCreator"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="Name of the Alarm" />

                <TimePicker
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Repeat Daily"
                    android:id="@+id/rDaily"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Repeat Weekly"
                        android:id="@+id/rWeekly"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:checked="false" />

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Create Alarm"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabList"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabClock"></LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tabInfo"></LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks